# AWS Backup, specify which volumes to backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, aws-backup

We are currently using AWS Backup for backing up our EC2 instances. AWS Backup creates snapshot of all attached EBS volumes.

We have couple of instances with attached multiple EBS volumes and we would like to specify to backup **only** system volume and skip the additional ones, is it possible to do this using AWS Backup?

If not, what is the best practice to do such thing? Could you please recommend me solution for this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "system volume"?

Comment: By system volume I mean "root device" where the OS is installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tags to get this functionality or not based on how/what you want. You can tag your root devices and then create a plan in aws backup. Now in the step of assigning the resources, select `Include specific resource types` and select **EBS** from `Resource type`.
You now have two options, select all the root devices manually or select based on tags (`Refine selection using tags`).

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to work since an EC2 Backup will always store the attached EBS data even if it is specifically excluded.
It seems that the only current solution is to create a Snapshot of each EBS Volume and use the approach from the AWS Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/backup-recovery/restore.html under "Creating or restoring an EC2 instance from an EBS snapshot" to get the job done.